Can I ask my company to reimburse flight ticket?
My previous employer had not cancelled my work visa in the UAE which resulted in me joining a new company. My new company is covering my flight expenses but they can’t give me a ticket without a visa. Therefore, I want to travel to the UAE a few days before the joining date to get my previous visa cancelled. Can I ask to pay for my ticket before and ask for them to pay me later once I get my visa?

Of course you can ask. They may say no, if this causes administrative problems or run afoul a corporate policy. Buts a perfectly valid question to ask.

As most things in the UAE are done by the sponsor, the cancellation is up to the former employer's to do it and you shouldn't need to do anything yourself (source)

@Hilmar's comment should be promoted to the answer. IMHO.

When your previous work cancels the visa, doesn't that mean you won't be able to work for the new company? Unless you have another visa - in which case why can't the new company get you a ticket based on the new visa?

If your work visa wasn’t canceled doesn’t that mean you have one? How did not cancelling your work visa result in you leaving your employer? Your question is confusing.

I don't understand. Why can't the new company reimburse you the ticket based on your old visa? If they're really worried about you not qualifying for the new visa, make the reimbursement only contingent on you being able to obtain the new visa as well.


Can I ask to pay for my ticket before and ask for them to pay me later once I get my visa?

Of course you can ask. They may say no, if this causes administrative problems or run afoul a corporate policy. But it is a perfectly valid question to ask.
If there is a problem you can discuss with them how they want to proceed and figure out a solution that works well for both of you. Surely you will get a better answer from the company than you would get from strangers on the internet (even of they are well meaning ones).
